# Is it possible to apply for Visa extension of a Nigerian visitor in the UK?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, nigerian-citizens, visa-extensions, weddings

I am UK citizen and I have a girlfriend who is Nigerian visiting me in the UK. Can I apply for visa extension as a partner for her. Not ready to marry

Answer (score 7):

There is no route to extend a visitor visa beyond the standard 6 months unless the visa holder is:

- a patient receiving medical treatment
- an academic and you still meet the eligibility requirements
- a graduate doing a clinical attachment or retaking the Professional and Linguistic Assessment Board (PLAB) test

Source: https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/extend-your-stay

Even giving notice of intention to marry https://www.gov.uk/marriages-civil-partnerships, and assuming the Home Office approved the request, would not mean that your girlfriend’s visit visa would be extended beyond the original 6 months.